# How to ensure that my Jobs in table has the correct status

Tags: c#, .net-core, autofixture, nsubstitute

I have an application that adds different type of Jobs that should be exectuted.

When the jobs are added to the table, they get the status "queued". When the jobs are exectured, they get the status "Running", and when an error occur, they get the status "Failed".

Now I would like to write some unit tests for this, to ensure for example that the job has the status Failed when an error occour.

I have tried to do something like this:

```
var provider = RegisterServices();
var jobRepo = provider.GetRequiredService<IJobRepository>();
var jobQueueService = provider.GetRequiredService<IJobQueueService>();

await SeedDb(jobRepo);
await jobQueueService.Enqueue(GetTrigger(1, 1), CancellationToken.None); // Add the jobs to the database with the status "Queued"


var theService = Substitute.For<IExecuteJobsService>();
theService
    .When(_ => _.ExecuteJobs(Arg.Any<CancellationToken>()))
    .Throw(new Exception("didn't work"));

var jobs = await jobRepo.Get(x => x.State == JobState.Failed, CancellationToken.None); // Returns 0
```

As you can see, im seeding my in memory db in the test with some jobs and then queue them. Then im trying to force an exception in somehow to get the jobs in a Failed status. But this don't work..

How can I test this?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a mock version of IExecuteJobsService and telling it to throw an exception when *ExecuteJobs* is invoked - but you never start the process of handling a job or dequeuing it.

I'm assuming your error handling is triggered in your IExecuteJobsService implementation, so you need to invoke the actual implementation of *ExecuteJobs*.

Let's say you have this implementation:

```
public class ExecuteJobsService : IExecuteJobsService
{
    private readonly IJobRepository _jobRepo;
    private readonly ISomeDependency _someDependency;
    public ExecuteJobsService(IJobRepository jobRepo, ISomeDependency someDependency)
    {
        _jobRepo = jobRepo;
        _someDependency = someDependency;
    }

    public void ExecuteJobs(CancellationToken token)
    {
        // gets the next job in queue
        var job = _jobRepo.GetNextQueuedJob();

        // start process the job
        try
        {
            // this method should be mocked to throw an exception,
            // then triggering your errorhandling
            _someDependency.Foo(job);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Set job status failed
        }
    }
}
```

Your test would then become:

```
public async Task GivenJobOnQueue_WhenFailDuringProcess_SetsStatusFailed()
{
    var provider = RegisterServices();
    var jobRepo = provider.GetRequiredService<IJobRepository>();
    var jobQueueService = provider.GetRequiredService<IJobQueueService>();

    await SeedDb(jobRepo);
    await jobQueueService.Enqueue(GetTrigger(1, 1), CancellationToken.None);

    // Create a mock of the dependency
    var someDependencyMock = Substitute.For<ISomeDependency>();
    // Setup Foo() to throw an exception when called
    someDependencyMock.When(_ => _.Foo()).Throw(new Exception("didn't work"));

    // Create your service and pass it the mocked object
    var theService = new ExecuteJobsService(jobRepo, someDependencyMock);

    // Start the processing of jobs
    theService.ExecuteJobs(CancellationToken.None);

    // Verify your result
    var jobs = await jobRepo.Get(x => x.State == JobState.Failed, CancellationToken.None);
}
```